# Constructing time series from multindex dataframe meeting certain conditions in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have the following log from a pizza store:

```
import pandas as pd

csv = [
    ['2019-05-01', '2019-05-01 18:30', 'pepperoni', 'small'],
    ['2019-05-01', '2019-05-01 21:00', 'pineapple', 'big'],
    ['2019-05-01', '2019-05-01 22:30', 'pepperoni', 'big'],
    ['2019-05-02', '2019-05-02 19:00', 'pineapple', 'small'],
    ['2019-05-02', '2019-05-02 20:30', 'pineapple', 'big'],
    ['2019-05-02', '2019-05-02 23:00', 'pepperoni', 'small']]

df = pd.DataFrame(csv, columns=["Working day", "Time of order", "Pizza type", "Pizza size"])
df["Working day"] = (pd.to_datetime(df["Working day"]))
df["Time of order"] = (pd.to_datetime(df["Time of order"]))
df = df.set_index(['Working day','Time of order'])
```

Now I have a multindex dataframe and I want to make some analysis. To do so, I want to construct time series based on the first index (Working day) applying certain conditions to the second index (Time of order) or the other columns.

For example, some desired outputs:

Each day, order closest to 19:00:00

```
                               Pizza type Pizza size
Working day Time of order                            
2019-05-01  2019-05-01 18:30:00  pepperoni      small
2019-05-02  2019-05-02 19:00:00  pineapple      small
```

Each day, first order after 19:00:00

```
                                Pizza type Pizza size
Working day Time of order                            
2019-05-01  2019-05-01 21:00:00  pineapple        big
2019-05-02  2019-05-02 19:00:00  pineapple      small
```

Each day, latest order with big pizza size:

```
                                Pizza type Pizza size
Working day Time of order                            
2019-05-01  2019-05-01 22:30:00  pepperoni        big
2019-05-02  2019-05-02 20:30:00  pineapple        big
```

Each day, order at 22:30:00

```
                                Pizza type Pizza size
Working day Time of order                            
2019-05-01  2019-05-01 22:30:00  pepperoni        big
2019-05-02  NaT                  NaN              NaN
```

And so on. How can I do such things?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a multi-index, try taking the difference to your `Time of order` column directly:

```py
### Skipping the `df = df.set_index(['Working day','Time of order'])` step:

# Calculate difference to 19:00 by seconds
df['time_difference'] = (df['Time of order'] - pd.to_datetime('19:00')).dt.seconds
```

The `.dt` method can be used to extract information from a `pandas datetime` object (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/basics.html#basics-dt-accessors)

Once you calculate your difference, then you could go about answering some of your specific questions using your new `time_difference` column.